# PL/SQL Date_Dimension Population of Data - DataWarehouse

Tags: oracle, plsql

Could use some guidance in pl/sql to add data to a table in Oracle using a stored procedure. Currently using OracleXE 11g. My stored procedure looks pretty naked at the moment and was hoping for some help. Here is my stored procedure (sp_DATE_DIMENSION) that takes two parameters and my definition of the DATE_DIMENSION table that I already created.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_DATE_DIMENSION(v_START_YEAR IN INT, v_END_YEAR IN INT) AS


DECLARE
v_CURRENT_DATE;
v_FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR;

BEGIN 

DELETE FROM DATE_DIMENSION;

WHILE v_CURRENT_DATE <= v_END_DATE
LOOP 

/

CREATE TABLE DATE_DIMENSION
(  
DATE_KEY DATE NOT NULL,
FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,
DAY_OF_WEEK NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL,
DAY_OF_MONTH NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
DAY_OF_YEAR NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL,
LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK_INDICATOR CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH_INDICATOR CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
WEEK_ENDING_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
MONTH_NUMBER NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL,
MONTH_NAME VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
YEAR_MONTH CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
QUARTER_NUMBER NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL,
YEAR_QUARTER CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
YEAR_NUMBER NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT DATE_DIMENSION_PK PRIMARY KEY (DATE_KEY)
)
```

/

To add:

The parameters are going to be two years. 
Example: exec sp_DATE_DIMENSION(2010,2012)

The procedure will populate the table with all the dates between start and end year. I would assume the key is a sequence between the 1st day of the start year, up until the last day of the end year. Let me know if you would agree. I also preferred a stored proc for my own learning.

Comment: What is this stored procedure supposed to do?  Please provide more detail.

Comment: You need to determine how each column value should be calculated for a given date (where does the key come from, a sequence? Local or ISO week numbers and start/end days? etc.); and explain what the parameters mean. Do you want every date from the first day of start_year to the last day of end_year, or something else? And do you really want a procedure for this when it can be done in plain SQL?

Comment: I edited the question I posted to answer the question. Thanks for responding @AlexPoole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite some time with some reading and help from felow Stackers I was able to complete what I had originally posted. So once again and in more detail, the stored procedure below takes two input parameters, i.e. (2001, 2005) and populates all dates in different formats from the first day of the START_YEAR up to the last day of END_YEAR.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE sp_DATE_DIMENSION(v_START_YEAR IN INT, v_END_YEAR IN INT) AS

--Declare two variables as DATE datatypes
v_CURRENT_DATE DATE;
v_END_DATE     DATE;

BEGIN

--Assign the start year and end year to it's respective variables
v_CURRENT_DATE := TO_DATE('0101' || v_START_YEAR, 'MMDDYYYY');
v_END_DATE     := TO_DATE('1231' || v_END_YEAR,   'MMDDYYYY');

--Clear/Dump what is currently stored in the table
DELETE FROM DATE_DIMENSION;

--Check the condition to see if the start year is less than the end year (Input Parameters)
WHILE v_CURRENT_DATE <= v_END_DATE
LOOP
--DATE_DIMENSION Table
INSERT INTO DATE_DIMENSION
(
    DATE_KEY,
    FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION,
    DAY_OF_WEEK,
    DAY_OF_MONTH,
    DAY_OF_YEAR,
    LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK_INDICATOR,
    LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH_INDICATOR,
    WEEK_ENDING_DATE,
    MONTH_NUMBER,
    MONTH_NAME,
    YEAR_MONTH,
    QUARTER_NUMBER,
    YEAR_QUARTER,
    YEAR_NUMBER       
)    
VALUES
(
    v_CURRENT_DATE,                                 --DATE_KEY
    TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'Day, Month DD, YYYY'), --FULL_DATE_DESCRIPTION
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'D')) -1,     --DAY_OF_WEEK
    TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'DD'),                   --DAY_OF_MONTH        
    TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'DDD'),                  --DAY_OF_YEAR
    CASE                                            --LAST_DAY_OF_WEEK_INDICATOR
        WHEN TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'FMDay') = 'Saturday' THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END,
    CASE                                            --LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH_INDICATOR
        WHEN LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) = TO_DATE(v_CURRENT_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END,
    CASE                                            --WEEK_ENDING_DATE OF CURRENT WEEK ENDING ON SATURDAY
        WHEN TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'FMDay') = 'Saturday' THEN v_CURRENT_DATE
        ELSE NEXT_DAY(v_CURRENT_DATE,'SATURDAY')
    END,
    TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'MM'),                   --MONTH_NUMBER
    TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'MONTH'),                --MONTH_NAME
    TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'MONTH YYYY'),           --YEAR_MONTH        
    TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'Q'),                    --QUARTER_NUMBER
    TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY Q'),               --YEAR_QUARTER
    TO_CHAR(v_CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY')                  --YEAR_NUMBER    

);
--Increment and assign the current date value to be re-evaluated
v_CURRENT_DATE := v_CURRENT_DATE + 1;

END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I get it.  You want to populate a table for a data warehouse for dates with all the aspects of the dates pulled out and stored for easier/faster queries in the warehouse.  Here's how I'd do it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_DATE_DIMENSION (v_START_YEAR IN INT, v_END_YEAR IN INT) AS
  l_start_date DATE;
  l_end_date DATE;

BEGIN
  l_current_date = to_date('1-JAN-' || v_start_year);
  l_end_date = to_date('31-DEC-' || v_end_year);

  WHILE l_current_date <= l_end_date LOOP

    INSERT INTO date_dimension VALUES (
      l_current_date, 
      to_char(l_current_date, 'Day, Month DDth, YYYY'),
      ...  for each column, use to_char and the proper format mask ...  
    );

    l_current_date := l_current_date + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: I'll try it out now. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Getting an error when I just run your script just to see if I can do a select query.